# beforeSend in axios

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I want to add a loading effect to my project.In jQuery Ajax we have an option called beforeSend and complete for this task.So we show the loading impact on beforeSend and hide it in complete function.Can we do the same task with axios?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        //show loading
    },
    complete: function() {
        //hide loading
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can do `show loading` before calling axios,and `hide loading` in `then` funciton, caused by axios return a promise.

example:

```js
let loading = true
axios.get('/user/12345').then((response) => {
  loading = false;
})
```

If you use `async` syntax, will be more easy:

```js
async funciton fetchSth() {
  let loading = true;
  await axios.get('/user/12345');
  loading = false;
}
```